# Dynamics Document Management with SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, solution, document-management

I have been trying to configure the Document Management for D365 with SharePoint Site in SharePoint Online. I have done this before so, I thought it is a simple process. But now it's giving me this warning: [image]

I tried the list component and also installed the Solution but I cannot activate the solution since the button is inactive for me. 
[image]

I am the site collection administrator. Is there anything I need to activate or any permissions that I am missing? I am stuck here, so any help from you guys would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you Started “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service” in Central Administrator ->Service Applications ->Manage services on server

Comment: @TARUN, the 'service applications' is not available in the online SharePoint center admin. I also tried installing the Admin Center but it does not appear in the Administrative tools.

Comment: Go to Central Administration of SharePoint Online, you need to be in SharePoint Administrator or Tenant Administrator role. Check in Apps who can install applications and try it under these roles.

Comment: I am the Site Collection Administrator right now. The main problem is, I can configure this easily in other environments with the same role and for the same SharePoint Site. There are two environments which are giving me this error. When I can configure the same site for other environments, how come this problem arises for other environments. Any Help?